# Fixed vs. absolute

Tags: html, css, position, fixed, absolute

So I've checked the site and I've seen questions close to what I am looking for but not exactly the same.

I am trying to figure out how to position an element so that when scrolled (up / down) the position is fixed, but when the browser is resize (left / right) the position is absolute or relative.

Essentially I want to place an element 10% (for example) from the top left of the browser window and have it stay there on scroll /window resize.

Comment: media-queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Based on your comment "Essentially I want to place an element 10% (for example) from the top left of the browser window and have it stay there on scroll /window resize" fixed position will give the exact solutions.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change position?

Comment: because fixed makes it static, it doesn't move left to right with the browser

Answer (score 4):

if what you want is always fixed in some position even if the browser is scrolled / resized, you may try this for your css

```
.fixedelement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%; /*my example*/
  height: 10%;
}
```